Jupyter Notebook Toolbar Icons - Re: Uninstalling nbextensions
I had installed nbextensions in order to hide cell input. I had installed it on juypter notebooks via my conda environment terminal. This lead to more issues than solving it.
I have uninstalled nbextensions according to my terminal and conda environment - but am unable to remove all these icons that were added by nbextensions. See image attached. enter image description here
Would anyone know how to reset my juypter notebooks toolbar back to default?
I tried all of the following commands in my command prompt:
pip uninstall jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
pip uninstall jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
jupyter contrib nbextension uninstall --user
pip uninstall jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter nbextensions_configurator disable
All to no avail.
